# How to press the second button with VBA Excel Internet Explorer

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I am trying to press a button with ID "run-report" the issue is that there is two buttons with the same ID and I want to press the second button.

```
Set tags = ie.Document.GetElementsByTagname("input") 
For Each tagx 
In tags If tagx.Value = "Run report" 
Then tagx.Click 
End If 
Next
```

This works for the first button but can not find a way to press the second one. Anyone got any tips?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Always helps to show the relevant HTML source...

Comment: The HTML is sadly behind a login and it is a platform done in speed rather then actuate coding. I dont feel like I have the authority to post the code from the page either. Sadly.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds strange two buttons having the same `id`, web developers tend to use unique information for this property because it's usually the reference for CSS and JavaScript... are you sure you don't mean the same `Value`? Anyway, you can always control such a problem by adding to your code a control variable that tells you if it's the first or the second time:

```
Set tags = ie.Document.GetElementsByTagname("input") 
meetFirst = False '<-- we didn't meet any first button with id = "myID" yet
For Each tagx In tags 
    If tagx.id = "myID" 
        If meetFirst = False Then
            meetFirst = True '<-- we met the first button
        Else '<-- if we get here, we are dealing with the second "myID" button
            tagx.Click
            Exit For '<-- we can end the loop
        End If
    End If 
Next
```

I have used the example with `tagx.id`, sticking to your sentence *the buttons have the same id and I want to press the second*. You can change the property to check with whatever you want (`.Value`, `.className` etc.)

Comment: Worked like I charm. Thanks! Just had to add a "Then" after If tagx.ID for other people who would like to use it. Thanks alot!

Comment: @NiklasAndersson if it works, please accept the answer (it will tell to other people who have the same problem that this is the solution)

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
ie.document.querySelectorAll("#run-report")(1).Click
```

The `querySelectorAll` method can retrieve a `nodeList` of all elements with id of `run-report`. You index into that for a particular element.

Sometimes the syntax is slightly different:

```
ie.document.querySelectorAll("#run-report").Item(1).Click
```